# Why does my Classic ASP website keep losing it's session?

Tags: session, asp-classic

Good Morning,

We have recently moved from a server to a VPS with an external supplier, both computers are running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

However since I moved it to the new server when you attempt to checkout and login it loses the session ... What I mean is that the products in the basket are lost and it logs the customer out, so they have to try over and over again.

From what I can see the settings in IIS are the same.

***Server Settings:***

**Application Pool** - 
V2.0, 
Classic.

**Session State** - 
In Process, 
Auto Detect, 
Time-out: 40, 
Regenerate Expired Session ID.

**ASP - Session Properties** - 
Enable Session State: True, 
Maximum Sessions: 4294967295,
New ID on secure connection: Ture.

Website: http://www.dibor.co.uk

Does anyone have any ideas on how to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

For the basics please have a look at the following link: [Session State Not Working? Check Your Web Garden](http://dotnetslackers.com/WSE/re-226656_Session_State_Not_Working_Check_Your_Web_Garden.aspx)

We are facing this problem too since about two weeks. Perhaps the idea with Fiddler in the link above is rather too technical.

On your webserver you can locally connect to IIS with a browser. This way you can figure out if the problem comes from IIS session handling or something in the HTTP channel is cutting out your ASPSESSIONID cookies. Localy on our webserver our website runs fine.
It is something in the HTTP communication like a firewall cutting out our ASPSESSIONID cookies and corrupting our ASP Classic session handling.